Efficient way to lookup prices based on date ranges
I'm playing around with importing my energy usage data into Python, and I'm trying to figure out a good way to do price lookups.
The unit energy price changes a few times a year, so I have ranges of dates and the unit price, for example:
start_date     end_date       unit_cost
----------     --------       ---------
2023-01-01     2023-03-31     0.2384
2023-04-01     2023-09-30     0.2761
2023-10-01     2024-01-31     0.2566

It should be safe to assume that the date ranges are contiguous, so potentially this could be simplified to just the start date for each unit price.
I then retrieve a list of daily unit consumption values and want to multiply that by the appropriate unit cost for the date.
There's clearly a number of dumb, brute-force ways to do this; iterating through a data structure and checking whether the current date falls between the start and end dates... but I'm thinking there must be a clever, Pythonic way to do this. I'm interested in efficiency in the sense of short, clear code rather than raw performance, but a fast algorithm could also be relevant!
Is there a data structure and/or module that applies to this use case?

This is a classic binary search problem. Put your data in a list of 3-tuples: (start_date, end_date, unit_cost). Now, you can do a binary search for a given date, to find the entry with a matching start/end date. Then pull the unit price out of that entry

I'd use a pandas dataframe, but you can use any other data structure you like. I think your question is off-topic because you're "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource".

A quick thanks to all for the responses. It'll take a few days for me to get to grips with the answers provided!

As an option: Using pandas dataframes to load in your data (assuming the sample data is structured exactly like that in a text file) you can just filter the dataframe to get the record you want:
prices.txt:
start_date     end_date       unit_cost
----------     --------       ---------
2023-01-01     2023-03-31     0.2384
2023-04-01     2023-09-30     0.2761
2023-10-01     2024-01-31     0.2566

Code:
import pandas as pd 
import datetime

df = pd.read_fwf(
    'prices.txt', 
    widths=[15,15,10], 
    names=['start_date','end_date','price'], 
    skiprows=2,
    parse_dates=['start_date','end_date'])

test_date = datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 1)
print(df[(df['start_date'] <= test_date) & (df['end_date'] >= test_date)])

Output:
    start_date  end_date    price
0   2023-01-01  2023-03-31  0.2384


Assuming you have the data in a text file exactly as shown in the question then it's just a case of building a list of lists, sorting the list, then doing a binary search that's designed to handle ranges. The dates are strings in the form of YYYY-MM-DD and can therefore be compared lexicographically.
def bsearch(_list, _item):
    lo = 0
    hi = len(_list) - 1
    while lo <= hi:
        m = (lo + hi) // 2
        start, end, _ = _list[m]
        if start <= _item <= end:
            return m
        if start < _item:
            lo = m + 1
        else:
            hi = m - 1
    return -1

with open("prices.txt") as prices:
    data = []
    for row in prices.readlines()[2:]: # skip first 2 lines
        data.append(row.split())
    data.sort() # only necessary if input data are not already sorted
    i = bsearch(data, "2024-01-31")
    if i >= 0:
        print(data[i][2])

Output:
0.2566


bisect could be useful here.

I'm not sure if there are any built-in python data structures for mapping a range of values (dates) to a single value (price), but you could always just quickly create your own. Since you don't need maximum performance, here's an example of a pretty short class that just extends from dict:
class RangeDict(dict):
    def lookup(self, target):
        for key, value in sorted(self.items(), reverse=True):
            if target >= key:
                return value

        raise KeyError

It can be a one liner as well if you still find it readable:
class RangeDict(dict):
    def lookup(self, target):  
        return next(v for k, v in sorted(self.items(), reverse=True) if target >= k)

An example use case:
from datetime import date

prices = RangeDict({
    date(2024, 1, 1): 100,
    date(2024, 2, 20): 120,
    date(2024, 3, 15): 40
})

prices.lookup(date(2024, 2, 21))
# Returns 120

